# 他のテーブルの特定のカラム情報が表示できない

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, knockout.js

#### 前提・実現したいこと

車両管理システムのマスタ画面を作成しています。
他のテーブル（'MtSections','MtEmployementClasses'）のデータをもってきてセレクトボックスで選択させ、名前で表示させたいです。

しかし、データの選択まではうまくいくのですが登録後に画面に表示されるのが数字になってしまっています。

#### 該当のソースコード

**MtEmployee.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');


class MtEmployee extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'MtSections' => array(
            'className' => 'MtSections',
            'foreignKey' => 'mt_section_id',
        ),
        'MtEmployementClasses' => array(
            'className' => 'MtEmployementClasses',
            'foreignKey' => 'mt_employement_class_id',
        )
        );


}
```

**MtEmployeesController**

```
class MtEmployeesController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array('MtEmployee','MtSections','MtEmployementClasses');
    public function index() {
        $this->set('mt_section_id', $this->MtSections->find('list'));
        $this->set('mt_employement_class_id', $this->MtEmployementClasses->find('list'));
    }
```

**index.ctp**

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: employees">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#edit" data-bind="click: showDetail">編集</a></td>
            <td data-bind="text: MtEmployee.mt_section_id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: MtEmployee.work_type"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: MtEmployee.mt_employement_class_id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: MtEmployee.employee_name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: MtEmployee.employee_number"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: MtEmployee.order_no"></td>
            <td><a href="#delete" data-bind="click: deleteDetail">削除</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**index.js**

```
function addEvents(employee) {

            /*** 詳細表示 ***/
            employee.showDetail = function() {

                self.detail.id(employee.MtEmployee.id);
                self.detail.orderNo(employee.MtEmployee.order_no);
                self.detail.mt_section_id(employee.MtEmployee.mt_section_id);
                self.detail.work_type(employee.MtEmployee.work_type);
                self.detail.mt_employement_class_id(employee.MtEmployee.mt_employement_class_id);
                self.detail.employee_name(employee.MtEmployee.employee_name);
                self.detail.employee_number(employee.MtEmployee.employee_number);


                openModal(employee, '.employee-edit-modal');

            }.bind(employee);
```

#### 試したこと

インターネットを元に、色々と試したのですが何も表示されなくなったり更新中で止まってしまいました。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

cakephpは2系です。
ソースコードは自分が関係あると思うところだけを載せました。
もし、情報が足りないようでしたらコメント欄にお願いします。
名前で表示させたい列は、MtSectionsのnameとMtEmployementClassesのnameです。
なにぶん、初心者ですがよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/226102

Comment: 「初心者かどうか」は質問の説明になりませんので、少なくともタイトルに含めるのは適切ではありません。 / 必要であればプロフィールの [自己紹介](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current) に記載しましょう。